# How to compare two arraycollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I populate a datagrid with an (arA).
This arraycollection is a resultEvent of a httpService.
arraycollection
As my datagrid must be uptodate, I use a timer to query database and see if new record exist.
Today, each time I do the query, I refresh the datagrid.
But, this orientation is not good for user experience.

So, I have a new idea, to store result of update httpservice in a new arraycollection (ArB) and compare both arraycollection. But I don't know how to do that.

Can, you help me or purpose better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for new items, or items that are deleted, or something else?  You'll have to write your own algorithm to compare the data sets.  You may also consider creating a new remote call that only returns updates.

Comment: Its better to compare and use Arrays rather than arrayCollection, you can get base array using source property of Array(), and update source property of dataGrid dataprovider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Flex, you may want to try `mx.utils.ObjectUtil` for comparison.

```
public function compare(arrayCollection1:ArrayCollection, arrayCollection2:ArrayCollection):Boolean
{
    if (arrayCollection1.length != arrayCollection2.length)
        return false;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < arrayCollection1.length; i++)
    {
        if (ObjectUtil.compare(arrayCollection1[i], arrayCollection2[i]) != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is computationally intensive; therefore, you may want consider changing your methodology to include a timestamp or index when data was last received.  Within your web service, that timestamp could be passed as a parameter.  Then your web service would be leaner returning only the delta from the last call.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can try approach like this:

1- Data stored in DB will have field updateDate, this is the latest update time of this field.

2- Every time inquiry for new/update/delete item, just load the update items. (with this approach, deleted item will not be really deleted from system, just update its flag to deleted).

3- When comparing updated array vs current array, you just need to compare the id of the object in current array vs id of object in updated array, and update it accordingly.

This approach would be similar to the comment from www.Flextras.com above.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this:

- Use an Array to act as a buffer.
- Set the buffer size to a reasonable size. Say 10 records.
- Populate the grid whenever the buffer is full or at instant you specify - Whichever is before.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you can do it in the following way:

## #1

each record has their's own id, so you can compair the local arraycollection and the remote arraycollection base on the id field, then add the new record to the local arraycollection.

## #2

add new api in the server to support paging with id.

for example:

`getRecord(fromid,-1)` will return the records from "from id "to the latest record. `getRecord(fromid,toid)` will return the records from and to.

Answer (score 0):

i would consider have a last_modify field in the response with the timestamp, so you may check besides for the length of the response, ie, if the last_modify field of the response is bigger that the previous last_modify is because there was a change in the data, but you will need some help from the backend to allow this change

Answer (score -1):

if both the array collection having same length:

```
public function foo(coll1:ArrayCollection, coll2:ArrayCollection):void 
{
    if (coll1.length == coll2.length) 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < coll1.length; i++) 
        {
            if (coll1[i].first != coll2[i].first || coll1[i].last != coll2[i].last) 
            {
                Alert.show("Different");
                return;
            }
       }
    }

   Alert.show("Same");
}
```

Comment: It can't be a solution. The coll1[i] is one of the items in the collection and is of type Object. There are no properties like first and last by default. That's why the expression coll1[i].first gives "undefined" as result. Let me know if I am wrong.